# How to get ServiceLocator from a Liferay module?

Tags: liferay

[ServiceLocator](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/7.0/javadocs/portal-impl/com/liferay/portal/template/ServiceLocator.html) is a convenient way to get Liferay service API objects.

While it is available by default to Velocity templates as `$serviceLocator`, I have not found a way to get hold of an instance from Java code.

How to get a ServiceLocator from within the Java code of a Liferay 7 module (OSGI)?

Comment: What keeps you from declaring proper dependencies through `@Reference`?

Comment: @OlafKock: Thank you for the tip! I looked up `@Reference`, and indeed it is what I need! I tried writing an answer based on your tip, I am a beginner but I hope it is correct :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Velocity templates use `serviceLocator`, Liferay modules have no need for it.

The correct way to get a service in a Liferay module is to follow these steps:

1) At the bottom of your class, add a reference to the service, for instance:

```
@Reference
protected com.liferay.journal.service.JournalArticleLocalService journalArticleLocalService;
```

2) If you get an error saying that the package or class is not found, then add the appropriate dependency to your `build.gradle` file, for instance:

```
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.api", version: "2.6.1"
compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.journal.service", version: "3.11.5"
```

then exit your IDE and run:

```
./gradlew clean eclipse
```

Comment: That's it. Saved me some typing (in the comment to your question) ;)